# SQL error happening: conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Below is my SQL query

please suggest something

```
select p.e_id as Employee_Id, p.ename as Name,p.eadd1 as Address,
 p.eprof as Profession,p.eactive as salary,
 (select count (d.pr_id) from employee_presency d 
 where d.e_id = p.e_id and d.t_date
 between '01-06-2013' and '31-06-2013')
  as presency,(select sum(c.payment) from emp_payment c 
  where c.e_id = p.e_id and c.pay_date
   between'01-06-2013'
   and '31-06-2013' ) as Salary  from  Employee p
```

Comment: I suggest you try looking at other similar questions. Some of them are now in the *Related* section on the right.

Comment: sorry for not providing server details

Comment: pay_date and t_date are defined as date datatype

Comment: 30 date worked thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your database is of the opinion that there is no 31st month.

Consider using `yyyy-mm-dd` date notation, which doesn't have the day v.s. month problem. For example:

```
'2013-06-31'
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't provide enough information to know for sure. But most dbms have a default date format, and if that's different from the formats you use, you'll get some kind of error message.

For example, in [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions203.htm) you might use an expression like `to_date('31-06-2013', 'dd-mm-yyyy')`. ([Oracle date format codes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/sql_elements004.htm#i34924))

Another possibility one or more of the columns "t_date" and "pay_date" are declared as char(n) or varchar(n) instead of being declared as "date", and they contain some data that can't be represented as a valid date. A varchar() column might contain a value like ''31-06-2@1#', or 'wibble'.